# Why does this code return $\frac{count}{2}$ instead of $count$?

Tags: graphs, loops

I am reading "Algorithms 4th Edition" by Sedgewick & Wayne.

The following method computes the number of self loops of an undirected graph $G$.
Why does this code return $\frac{count}{2}$ instead of $count$?
I think self loop appears in adjacency list only once.

```
// number of self-loops
public static int numberOfSelfLoops(Graph G) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int v = 0; v < G.V(); v++)
        for (int w : G.adj(v))
            if (v == w) count++;
    return count/2;   // self loop appears in adjacency list twice
}
```

Thank you for your comment, Zach Langley.
Now I have read the following code, and I understand why the above code is right.

```
 /**
 * Adds the undirected edge v-w to this graph.
 *
 * @param  v one vertex in the edge
 * @param  w the other vertex in the edge
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException unless both {@code 0 <= v < V} and {@code 0 <= w < V}
 */
public void addEdge(int v, int w) {
    validateVertex(v);
    validateVertex(w);
    E++;
    adj[v].add(w);
    adj[w].add(v);
}
```

Comment: This is a consequence of how `Graph` is implemented. Adding an edge (u, v) adds v to u's adjacency list and u to v's adjacency list. When u = v, u gets added twice to its own adjacency list.

Comment: @ZachLangley Thank you very very much. I have read addEdge(int v, int w) now.